# Aggregate an array based on the dimension names

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate an array based on the dimension name, in an efficient way.

```
ex_array <- array(1:10000, dim = c(100, 10, 10),
                  dimnames = list(Col1 = c(rep(10,50), rep(20, 50)),
                                  Col2 = 1:10,
                                  Col3 = 1:10))
```

Now I want to aggregate this array based on the names of the first dimension. This dimension has 2 different names (10 and 20) and therefore the new array should have a dimension of 2 by 10 by 10. All the values with dimension name 1 equal to 10 should be summed and the values with dimension 1 equal to 20 should be summed.

Is there some clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**reshape2.** I think reshape2 is the best fit here, if you're willing to use packages:

```
library(reshape2)
res = acast(melt(ex_array), Col1 ~ Col2 ~ Col3, fun.aggregate = sum)

str(res)
#  int [1:2, 1:10, 1:10] 1275 3775 6275 8775 11275 13775 16275 18775 21275 23775 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "10" "20"
#   ..$ : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#   ..$ : chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

I think this would also collapse duplicates in the other dimensions' names (if there were any).

---

**base R.** You can use `rowsum`, but it's clunky here because it's designed for matrices

```
res2 = array(, c(2, 10, 10), dimnames = lapply(dimnames(ex_array), unique))
res2[] = sapply(seq_len(dim(ex_array)[3]), function(k) 
  rowsum(ex_array[,,k], rownames(ex_array[,,k])))
```

Comment: As I was carrying out my machinations I thought to myself that this was probably going to look a lot more compact if done by `reshape2` or `splitstackshape` or `dplyr` functions. (And it delivers what I think is the proper result as well.)

Answer (score 2):

To do it for only one of the dimension names, it could just be:

```
 apply( ex_array[dimnames(ex_array)[[1]] == "10",,], 2:3, sum)
```

If you then wrap that in an `sapply` call you get a `2 x prod(N1, N2)` matrix with the proper information. I worked with a shrunken version of your example dataset:

```
ex_array <- array(1:360, dim = c(10, 6, 6),
                  dimnames = list(Col1 = c(rep(10,5), rep(20,5 )),
                                  Col2 = 1:6,
                                  Col3 = 1:6))
str( sapply(unique(dimnames(ex_array)[[1]]), function(x) apply( ex_array[dimnames(ex_array)[[1]] == x,,], 2:3, sum)) )
 int [1:36, 1:2] 15 65 115 165 215 265 315 365 415 465 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "10" "20"
```

.... but it's in column-major order and to recast it to a 2 x N1 x N2 array you then need to transpose it, so the "10" values are the top row and the "20" values are the second row. Then those values can be recast into a 2 x N1 xN2 array. You can think of it as first placing "10" value in the proper slice coordinate, followed by placing the "20" value coord , and so on , and so on:

```
 target <- array( t(     # need to process the transpose
                sapply(unique(dimnames(ex_array)[[1]]), 
                   function(x) apply( ex_array[dimnames(ex_array)[[1]] == x,,], 2:3, sum))
                   ), 
                 dim= c( length( unique( dimnames(ex_array)[[1]])), dim(ex_array)[2:3]) )
 str(target)
# int [1:2, 1:6, 1:6] 15 40 65 90 115 140 165 190 215 240 ...
```

I then checked that the first slice was the same as the single name result I got at the beginning:

```
target[1,,] == apply( ex_array[dimnames(ex_array)[[1]] == "10",,], 2:3, sum)
    Col3
Col2    1    2    3    4    5    6
   1 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   2 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   3 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   4 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   5 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
   6 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`tapply` could be used inside `apply` to *aggregate an array based on the dimension names*.

```
. <- apply(ex_array, 2:3, tapply, dimnames(ex_array)[[1]], sum)
str(.)
# int [1:2, 1:10, 1:10] 1275 3775 6275 8775 11275 13775 16275 18775 21275 23775 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#  ..$     : chr [1:2] "10" "20"
#  ..$ Col2: chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#  ..$ Col3: chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```